# How to change the base url of the wiki

Tags: mediawiki

I want to change the wiki page base url; I've tried by editing $wgServer parameter on the LocalSettings.php file. I can land on the main page using the new url (say : http://wiki.mydomain.com) , however the links on the wiki still contains the previous base url, in other words the previous site urls were not updated with the new base url. I'm using Media wiki 1.21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you been using an absolute path in [$wgArticlePath](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgArticlePath)? That's the parameter that's used to construct (almost) all links in your wiki!

Comment: I didn't change the default value of $wgArticlePath which was empty (""). Anyways thanks for pointing out the parameter, problem solved after updating $wgArticlePath parameter to the new domain name ($wgArticlePath = "http://wiki.mydomain.com").

Answer (score 4):

In your LocalSettings.php file, set `$wgServer` to the domain name of your wiki server, but leave off the URL path component. Set `$wgScriptPath` to the URL path of the wiki on the server. For example if the wiki is located at "http://portal.example.com/wiki", then set these variables as follows:

```
$wgServer = "http://portal.example.com";
$wgScriptPath = "/wiki";
```